# Best-practise: Dealing with prerequesitews on different operation systems with Wix and Bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, bundle

This is more a best-practise question.
We ran into several issues over the last months with our setup. We have a standard msi setup bundled in a bootstrapper setup using Wix 3.10. Basically we used the bundle just for the ability to create a smart user wpf interface for the setup, but over the years the requirements have grown so we added prerequesites to the bundle.

1. Cascading .Net dependencies which also depend on the OS

We updated our project to .Net 4.6, so we added this framework to the setup with the following condition:

```
<PackageGroup Id="Netfx4FullInternal">
    <ExePackage Id="Netfx4FullInternal" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
        DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6"
        DetectCondition="(Netfx4FullVersion >= &quot;393295&quot;) AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR (Netfx4x64FullVersion>=&quot;393295&quot;))" 
        InstallCommand="/passive /norestart" 
        SourceFile="..\..\..\..\Common\PayloadBundle\NDP46-KB3045557-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe">
    </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

This works fine on Windows 7 (.Net is installed afterwards) and Windows 10 (.Net installation is skipped). But on a very fresh Windows 8.1 (maybe 8.0 also, not sure at the moment) the setup fails. The (Microsoft) log file for .Net says, that .Net needs another KB to be installed (unfortunately I have this in german only):

```
1.Das Update zu KB2919355 muss installiert werden, bevor Sie dieses Produkt unter Windows 8.1 oder Windows Server 2012 R2 installieren.
```

This KB 2919355 can’t be installed on this system without having another kb installed before. Since we had to accept that there are constellations and configurations of several systems we came to the decision not to add all those prereqs in our setup – another reason is the expected growth of the setup if we did.
Most problems can be solved when the users’ system is up to date so that is what we write in our readme, but how should we deal with these problems?

2. Hotfixes for each system and bit width
   Another big issue is the changed dealing with culture info since .Net 4.6. Unfortunately, our user interface is since 4.6 a pure language mix, it seems that each assembly starts with a specific language and our language switching mode only changes the language for the main executing assembly. No matter whose fault this is, but Microsoft released a 4.6 hotfix that addresses this issue. But there are hotfixes for Win7 (single file), Windows 8 (each per 32- and 64bit), Windows 8.1 (each per 32- and 64bit) and so on. We don’t want to add all those files into our setup for size reasons but also we don’t want to be too specific in our setup. E.g. Microsoft changed the VersionNT for Windows 10 from 6.4.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 which broke our setup, so we don’t want to check to finely granular but want to inform the user exactly what he should do and what is missing.
   How do you address this issue? What is the way we should go?

Comment: I would just fail with the error mentioned in the .net log. It should not be your responsibility to handle all the conditions needed to install KB fixes on every OS/Flavour of Windows. As you discovered, there are severeal requisites for each KB and each OS can have several KB prerequisites to install a certain KB. This is why Windows Update exists. If the end user has no outside internet access they need to get their IT department to handle installing the KB fixes for the speicifc OS required to let your install complete.

Comment: I agree with you in toto. Right now I only show the user a return code and a common failure message since I do not know how to obtrain  detailed information about the error. Is there a possibility to get the entry from the net.log file (no file system operations please)? In the ApplyComplete-Event I get the information that the installation went wrong, but no real error message. Could you name me the event that I should use to get the information that something went wrong in common and what went wrong in detail?

Comment: Yeah the .net installer return codes are not too helpfule because you're actually getting the return code of the setup.exe which basically just extracts the .net package and runs the correct OS installer from within that package. This setup.exe can return a completely different return code than the .net installer. You will probably have to open up and read the .net install log to get the real error code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I show a message when Net failed and a link which directs the customer to microsoft. Anything else is up to the user .-)